# Is there a java utility to produce http multi-part responses?

Tags: java, http, response, multipart

I am building a web-service that returns a multipart response.  I know the format for constructing a multi-part response; and I will build my own tools if I can't find existing tools.

Perhaps I just need help with my google-foo.  Everything I find is about POSTing or consuming multi-part messages.   Nothing about producing multi-part responses.

Comment: A more useful Google keyword may be *comet* and/or *multipart/x-mixed-replaced*.

Comment: Did you find a suitable library or did you end up building your own? I'm hitting the same problem now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use oreilly servlets http://www.servlets.com/cos/

An example is in the javadoc: http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartResponse.html

```
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartResponse

//javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse res
MultipartResponse multi = new MultipartResponse(res);

multi.startResponse("text/plain");
out.println("On your mark");
multi.endResponse();

try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

multi.startResponse("text/plain");
out.println("Get set");
multi.endResponse();

try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

multi.startResponse("image/gif");
ServletUtils.returnFile(req.getRealPath("/images/go.gif"), out);

multi.finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Apache HttpClient project? I haven't looked at it since it broke out from the Apache Commons stuff, but I know it did a lot with multi-part responses.

This is for consuming - not sure if there is anything for producing, but it might be a place to start.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html

Comment: This is not for *consuming* multipart **responses**. HttpClient *produces* multipart **requests**. An example of a consumer of multipart requests would be the [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/). OP is specifically asking for *producing* multipart **responses**. I'm not sure if HttpClient supports *consuming* multipart responses. Multipart responses are pretty rare.

Comment: HttpClient will consume multi-part responses.  I could not find any facility for producing mulit-part responses.