# Javax Servlet - Multipart as response

Tags: java, servlets

Based on [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html), the HttpServletResponse from Javax.servlet states the following:

> To mix binary and text data, for example, to create a multipart response, use a ServletOutputStream and manage the character sections manually.

I search around but could not found any example. I need to use **Javax.servlet** to be able to return a multi-part (image/jpeg + application/json).

Comment: There are libraries for this, and it's a known format. What specifically are you asking for?

Comment: I have to return a binary encoded image, and a json object that stores more informations. We are using Javax.servlet, and I wanted to re-use this lib in order to create the multi-part response.

Comment: I understand that part--I'm asking what you want as a response to this question. I'd probably just search the web for examples (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/4808806/438992) because requesting someone to write the code is OT, requests for libraries or tutorials are OT, etc.

Comment: I saw that library like [this](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartResponse.html) which look easy to create the Multi-part, but how can I provide it to my HttpServletResponse afterward ?

Comment: I understand, its just that Im trying to stay in the bound of the existing project that I got put on (PS: Im C++ dev put a java project, so Im lost...) and all the response I created with Javax.Servlet, I dont think that using a second library (similar to what I/You link) will fit with the rest of the code.

Comment: https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781565923911/blob/master/src/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartResponse.java, check the Javadocs. If you don't want to use a library then you'll need to construct the multi-part response manually.

Comment: As stated in the documentation _manage the character sections manually_ to create the multi-part myself, but I dont get it...

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for that, I just dont know java/web enough for that. I will build it myself thank!

Comment: The RFC is what you'll need to know to build it yourself. Personally... I'd use a library.

Comment: I would too, but not my company... :) So lets loose time.

Comment: Maybe C++ programmers don't like to use libraries, I don't know, but Java programmers do. It's totally normal.

Comment: No no, I like to use lib, it just that my company is a bit back in the past and still use java 1.6 and 2002 stuff and does want to update. But our C++ department is up-to-date with C++17 standard, etc.